# What does the two first coordinates in "rect" argument for matplotlib axes?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

According to https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html and https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html the input to the axes is `rect=[left,bottom,width,hight]` but it does not seem like `left/bottom` does anything.

The following plots below (seems) identical.

```py
plt.axes([0.5,10000,1,1])
plt.plot(range(100),np.sin(range(100)))
plt.show()
```

```py
plt.axes([0,10000,1,1])
plt.plot(range(100),np.sin(range(100)))
plt.show()
```

```py
plt.axes([0,0,1,1])
plt.plot(range(100),np.sin(range(100)))
plt.show()
```

EDIT:

Using VSCode as IDE and matplotlib version 3.1.2

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken I think the `rect` is ignored unless there is more than one `axes` added to a `figure` instance

Comment: the last two arguments changes the rectangle as expected

Comment: I was mistaken.... What version of matplotlib are you using? And which backend? Can you include screenshots of the plots as they are displayed with `plt.show()`? I'm having difficulty replicating what you describe

Comment: Edited regarding IDE and version.
Do you get different "rectangles"/plots if you run those three examples ?

Comment: I do, running them from the terminal on Ubuntu 18.04 with Matplotlib 3.1.2. It would seem the issue may be with the way VSCode is displaying the plots. I am curious if you notice a change when there are multiple subplots in a single figure?